# How do I change from an alert message to a regular text output?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code snippet of my function that will output the total calculated GPA which is:

```
alert("GPA =  " + eval(gpa));
```

However, I do not want it outputted as an alert.

I want it outputted in regular text.

So how do I change that so in HTML it will just output it in regular text instead of an alert ?

Is there a way to just replace the

> alert

part of the code with something else ?

Comment: [tag:java] is ***not*** [tag:javascript] - please ensure you've tagged your language appropriately.

Comment: Also, stop using `alert`. If you want to debug, use the Console API. If you want to put content on the page, literally do that: put content on the page.

Comment: @hershey10, maybe you are looking for `console.log("GPA = " + gpa())` ?

Comment: If your html element id is **gpa**, then in you js-file use document.getElementById("gpa").innerHTML = "GPA = " + eval(gpa);

Answer (score 2):

First create a div where you want to show text

```
<div class="text-message" style="display:none;"></div>
```

And change alert message with

```
$(".text-message").text("GPA =  " + eval(gpa)).show();

 OR to animate it

$(".text-message").text("GPA =  " + eval(gpa)).fadein();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like following with **HTML + JavaScript**.

```js
function gpa(param1 = 1, param2 = 2){
let resultGPA = param1 + param2; 
console.log("GPA = " + resultGPA);
document.getElementById('evalElement').innerHTML = resultGPA;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<button name="btn" onclick='gpa()'>Calculate GPA</button>
<p id = "evalElement"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

This should help you achieve your goal!

Answer (score 0):

If your html element **id** is **gpa**, then in your **JavaScript**-file use following:

**document.getElementById("gpa").innerHTML = "GPA = " + eval(gpa);**

Answer (score 0):

## Step 1

Let's change your alert code to:

```
myAlert("GPA =  " + eval(gpa));
```

## Step 2

Implement `myAlert`

```
function myAlert(content) {
    let context = document.getElementById('message-block');
    context.display = 'block';
    context.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = content;
}
```

## Step 3

Create the structure:

```
<div id="message-block" style='display: none;'>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="this.parentNode.display = 'none';"
</div>
```

```js
    let gpa = "'a'+'b'";

    function myAlert(content) {
        let context = document.getElementById('message-block');
        context.style.display = 'block';
        context.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = content;
    }

    myAlert("GPA =  " + eval(gpa));
```

```html
<div id="message-block" style='display: none;'>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';">
</div>
```